# Como imprimir a partir de un reporte c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Hola gente que tal? lo que estoy tratando de hacer es usar printdialog pero me imprime el documento en blanco. Por lo que leí tengo que usar el evento printpages para que me "Imprima" el texto pero los ejemplos que vi lo hacen leyendo un documento existente en el disco, en mi caso yo estoy generando un reporte a partir de la base de datos y no se si hay alguna forma de que le pueda asignar ese reporte al printdocument??.

De momento tengo la vista del reporte en el crystalReportViewer

```
  PrintDialog p = new PrintDialog();
  PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
  doc.DocumentName = reporte.SummaryInfo.ReportTitle;//reporte es un objeto del tipo reportDocument, el cual ya contiene los datos de la BD
  p.Document = doc;
  if(p.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
  {
        doc.Print();
  }
```

Esto me imprime una hoja en blanco porque tengo que usar el evento PrintPages